# Twitter4J retweet with a message

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

How to retweet with a message?

I know that retweeting a tweet without a message is like this:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.retweetStatus(statusId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to `quote` a tweet. It is just sending tweet that contains another tweet's link.

Example:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
String tweetContent = "I am quoting this tweet using twitter4j https://twitter.com/t4j_news/status/1054872709203550208"
Status updatedStatus = twitter.updateStatus(tweetContent);
System.out.println("Status updated to: " + updatedStatus.getText());
```